# App sends location data to website

Tags: javascript, php, ios, google-maps

**Explaining the idea and first steps**

Today, I had the idea to do a website which displays my current position. I searched in the App Store for an App and found [one](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/sendlocation/id377724446?mt=8) named [SendLocation](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/sendlocation/id377724446?mt=8). This App provides an interface for sending `GET` requests to an server with some geometrical data. This is how the data gets send:

```
http://yourserver.com/yourscript.php?lat=***&lon=***&speed=***&heading=***&vacc=***&hacc=***&altitude=***&deviceid=**&battery=***&ts=***&quick=***&background=***
```

**File Structure**

```
./location.php
./data.json
./index.html
```

**Writing the server side script**

After setting the app up and achieving the connection, I wrote an php script to get the data and store it into an `JSON` file to use it for example on a website. I don't want to set up a database for this and want to have this in an accessible file, so storing it in a `.json` file was totally easy and fast.

```php
<?php

  if (file_exists('data.json')) {
      $current_data = file_get_contents('data.json');
      $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
      $formdata = array(
            'lat' => $_GET['lat'],
            'lon' => $_GET['lon'],
            'speed' => $_GET['speed'],
            'heading' => $_GET['heading'],
      );
      $array_data[] = $formdata;
      $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
      if (file_put_contents('data.json', $final_data)) {
          echo 'Data saved successfully';
      }
  } else {
      echo 'JSON File not exits';
  }
```

**Access the data from the frontend**

I am going on with parsing the `.json` file and get the data of the last entry which is my current likely position. After, with the `lat` and `lon`, I do a Google Maps API call and get my real name position and log it to the console (yet).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>This is my location</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
      });
      $.getJSON("data.json").then(function (json) {
        // get latest position
        var lastElement = json[json.length - 1];

        // extract coordinates from position
        var lat = lastElement.lat;
        var lon = lastElement.lon;
        console.log(lat);

        // get name of coordinates
        getAddress(lat, lon);

        // get adress from google
        function getAddress(latitude, longitude) {
          var key = "api-key-goes-here";
          $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," +
            longitude + "&key=" + key,
            function (json) {
              console.log(json);
              console.log(json.results[9].formatted_address);
            });
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshots of console output**

[image: screenshot of console]

**My questions**

1. How can I hide the API key of the Google Map service to make it more secure?
2. Which improvements can be made to make the `GET` writing the `.json` more safe? I though about limit the writing to 3 a day or similar.
3. How can I hide the `data.json` from Google or normal visitors of my page, that only my code can access the file, is this even possible?
4. What can I do to make the JS faster and maybe more secure?
5. What else can be done?

**Any feedback really appreciated.**

Comment: To the close voters: this is not a feature request. This is a request for review with specific questions because the OP has thought well enough ahead and acknowledges the issues the code currently has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One thing you can do to secure your Google API key is to make the whole request to Google Map API on the server. So, instead of having a call from the frontend to Google API, you create a new `GET` request on the server that just wraps the call to Google API. And then, from your website, just make a request to your server instead to Google API.
2. If by *safe* you mean "I want **every** request to be written in the file and not to lose any data because of parallel requests", then you need some sort of locking mechanism. I'm not a PHP developer, and I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve this. A quick search on the internet for *PHP lock* resulted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325806/best-way-to-obtain-a-lock-in-php) and [this](https://github.com/php-lock/lock). So once you have some way of locking, you just need to surround your the `true` part of your condition with the locking mechanism.
3. You can do so by configuring your web server. If you're using Apache, then you can take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679524/block-direct-access-to-a-file-over-http-but-allow-php-script-access).
4. I don't see any problem with your JS. You are using JQuery for making requests to the server and I guess this is fine. If you would to query for some HTML element, then I think that native APIs outperform JQuery, so that would be a thing to take into consideration. Maybe consider using native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) if you use JQuery only for the server call. This will only speed up the page load time, since the browser won't need to load the remote library.
5. I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: thank you very much, the help is really appreciated. maybe there are some other answers and I leave this answer for now with not marking it as the accepted one. will do that if there are no other answers.

Comment: I'm not here for the "most accepted answers", I'm here to spread the knowledge, so no worries :) Glad you find it helpful.